# React testing library with redux-form issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-testing-library

Having an issue trying to test redux-forms components.  I keep getting an error  `FormSection must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()` Here is test code.

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import { render, screen, cleanup, fireEvent} from '@testing-library/react'
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import ContactInformation from '../components/FormSections/ContactInformation'


// Create a reducer that includes the form reducer from redux-form
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

const renderContactInformation = () => {
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ContactInformation />
    </Provider>,
  )
}

describe("<ContactInformation />", () => {
  test('it should render fields', () => {
    renderContactInformation()
    const input = screen.getByLabelText("email")
    console.log(input)
        }
      )

})
```

any thoughts?  These seems like it should work but I think I am at a lost or perhaps I just confused my self.  Any help will greatly be appreciated.